# VirtualBox access virtualhost from guest (android x86)

Tags: android, virtualbox, android-x86

I created a VM in VirtualBox with Android 4.4 as OS (image downloaded from android-x86.org).

I wanna use it for testing web projects, stored on my local machine (Mac OS X 10.9). On that machine a web server is running and a project url could be project-xy.dev (virtual host).

I am not able to access this url in a browser of the guest OS.

Is it possible to do this?
It works with Windows XP in Parallels and with iOS-Simulator.

Thanks,
christoph

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if I am understanding your question completely.

Are you trying to access the project created on the VM through the host machine, or are you trying to access a project created on the host through the VM.

Either way I would create a shared drive through the Virtual Box GUI

[image]

That way if you create your projects in this shared folder either machine will be able to access them.

Comment: Edited my question. It's about reaching a virtual host domain on my host OS from my guest OS.

Comment: If the site is not "live" meaning you have not setup a domain name and server to host your html files then you need to have access to the actual source files to view it in the browser on the host machine. To do so save all the files in a shared folder like the answer above suggests. Then on the host machine open those shared files.

Comment: The project has it's own url: http://project.dev. To use your words: it's "live". It's possible to visit that page from host System (Mac OS), iOS Simulator, Windows XP in Parallels.

iOS Simulator is a emulated system only, with access to local dns of Mac OS, Windows XP in Parallels has a manipulated hosts file, where the domain of project is mapped to the hosts IP.

Don't know who to do that in Android VM. I tried to setup a Proxy Solution, but i am too dumb :)

Anyway, thanks for answering

Comment: If the site is live then all you should have to do is open the page on a web browser in the Android Vm. However I did click on the "project.dev" link you provided and was not able to visit the site. So I would guess that it may not be a live site.

Comment: Dear Randy, project.dev is a domain on my LOCAL machine! You can't open *.dev, because it's not a valid top level domain